# can we check remote login information using finger command

Tags: linux, centos-6, finger

In man page of finger it's showing

> Finger may be used to look up users on a remote machine. The format is to specify a user as “user@host”, or “@host”

so I tried

> [max@localhost ~]$ finger max1@x.x.x.x

Then it's showing this error

> finger: cannot create socket / connect host

what is the reason?

I need output by using finger command only

I am using `Centos 6`

---

**update**

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install finger-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.hns.net.in
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * extras: mirrors.hns.net.in
 * updates: mirrors.hns.net.in
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package finger-server.i686 0:0.17-39.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                Arch          Version               Repository     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 finger-server          i686          0.17-39.el6           base           15 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 15 k
Installed size: 11 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
finger-server-0.17-39.el6.i686.rpm                       |  15 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : finger-server-0.17-39.el6.i686                               1/1 
  Verifying  : finger-server-0.17-39.el6.i686                               1/1 

Installed:
  finger-server.i686 0:0.17-39.el6                                              

Complete!
```

There is no daemon called `fingerd`

> [root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --list | grep -i fingerd

only `finger` service its showing and it's on

```
[root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --list | grep -i finger
    finger:         on
```

but still same problem...

Answer (score 3):

This will only work if the remote host is running a finger daemon that will respond to the query, but it's been many years now since it was common for hosts to run one of those.

Comment: what is the daemon name?

Comment: "fingerd", following the convention of daemons ending in 'd'

Comment: The package you want is `finger-server` but if the machine is internet accessible you probably want to think about restricting who can access it in some way.

Comment: Most SAs disable the finger service for security reasons.